# Passing method as parameter in PHP

Tags: php, function, parameters

I have a class in PHP like this:

```
class RandomNumberStorer{

     var $integers = [];

     public function store_number($int){
         array_push($this->integers, $int);
     }

     public function run(){
         generate_number('store_number');
     }
}
```

...elsewhere I have a function that takes a function as a parameter, say:

```
function generate_number($thingtoDo){ 
     $thingToDo(rand());
}
```

So I initialise a `RandomNumberStorer` and run it:

```
$rns = new RandomNumberStorer();
$rns->run();
```

And I get an error stating that there has been a 'Call to undefined function store_number'. Now, I understand that that with `store_number`'s being within the `RandomNumberStorer` class, it is a more a method but is there any way I can pass a class method into the `generate_number` function?

I have tried moving the `store_number` function out of the class, but then I then, of course, I get an error relating to the reference to `$this` out of the context of a class/ instance.

I would like to avoid passing the instance of `RandomNumberStorer` to the external `generate_number` function since I use this function elsewhere.

Can this even be done? I was envisaging something like:

```
 generate_number('$this->store_number')
```

Comment: Try: `generate_number(array($this, 'store_number'))`

Comment: @elclanrs It worked! No idea why. How does `generate_number` know what to do with an array?

Comment: It's a PHP feature, check answer below, has good explanation.

Comment: Apart from being a dupe, why would a RandomDataStorer have a method run? Either your class stores RandomNumbers, which makes it a Collection/Array data type of thing. Or it generates numbers, which makes it a Service kind of thing. Why would it do both? This seems to be much more a design problem than anything else.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to describe the `RandomNumberStore::store_number` method of the current instance as a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). The manual page says to do that as follows:

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an
>   object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

So what you would write is:

```
generate_number([$this, 'store_number']);
```

As an aside, you could also do the same in another manner which is worse from a technical perspective, but more intuitive:

```
generate_number(function($int) { $this->store_number($int); });
```

Comment: How would using a closure be worse from a technical perspective?

Comment: It's arguably better as it isn't using any string literals.